# What happens in the case of a tie in Clan Wars?

Tags: clash-of-clans

When there is a clan war, what happens in the case of a tie? Does it default to some of the stats used to describe the clan war? or does it have like a deathmatch?

Comment: Why was this question marked as a duplicate of a newer question when it already has an upvoted answer? Also that question is not a duplicate. It is about a specific tiebreaker mechanic introduced after this question was asked. See meta post: [Is a question a duplicate just because it asks for something that can be part of another question's answer?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7359/4797)

Comment: @galacticninja: This is marked as a duplicate because the upvoted, accepted answer here is now incorrect and should be downvoted or deleted. The newer question contains the correct answer, which would perfectly answer this question as well since they are essentially asking for the same information. "Is there a tiebreaker?" and "How does the tiebreaker work?" now results in identical answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the two clans have the same amount of stars at the end of the war, whichever clan has a higher average destruction will win. In the unlikely event that the two clans have the same average damage, the war will end in a draw, and both clans will receive reduced loot, but more than if they had lost.

Here is a screenshot of a tie:

[image]
<sup>Image from [this thread](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/377817-The-matchup-we-ve-all-been-waiting-for%21-Team-Y-O-L-O-vs-Reddit-Troopers?highlight=match%20reddit) on the forums</sup>

However you wont receive all of your war loot if it is a draw:

**Win:** 100% of war loot

**Lose:** 30% of war loot

**Draw:** 40% of war loot

Comment: This is no longer correct.

Comment: In a recent close game I saw that "Average destruction" was displayed out to 2 decimal places instead of 1 like in the screenshot here, which leads me to suspect that the chance of a draw has been greatly reduced - probably only if "average destruction" is the same to a hundredth of a percent.