# How does the new Tie-Breaker work?

Tags: clash-of-clans

In Clash of Clans there was an update on 9/16 adding a Tie-breaker into the wars, can anybody explain in detail how this mechanism works?

Comment: It literally says whoever has more percent destroyed. Did you read it?

Comment: No, That is not what I read... I read the two most heroic attacks go up against eachother and whoever got the highest percent the fastest won.

Comment: From the patch notes: "if the score is even at the end of the war, the Clan with more destruction percentage in their best attacks will be the victor!"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens in the case of a tie in Clan Wars?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/183615/what-happens-in-the-case-of-a-tie-in-clan-wars)

Comment: @Dragonrage I don't think they are duplicates. This question's about a specific tiebreaker mechanic introduced after that older question was asked. See meta post: [Is a question a duplicate just because it asks for something that can be part of another question's answer?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7359/4797)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [2015-09-17 Spell revamp & War tiebreaker update](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/844976-Update-17-09-Spell-revamp-War-tiebreaker):

> [..] if the score is even at the end of the war, the Clan with more destruction percentage in their best attacks will be the victor!

Comment: You should note in this answer what happens if the destruction percentage is also equal.